# How to evenly space vertices along an ellipsis-loop without changing its profile

Tags: mesh, geometry

I have a number of loops that define the profile of sections of a fuselage (used a cylinder primitive). As you can imagine, these sections are varying sizes by design...most are slightly flattened along Z to follow the fuselages' design. There are then loops running along the Fuselage's Y axis. The problem is that all these Y oriented loops are not evenly spaced along the length of each of the Vertical fuselage sections, so the shading of fuselage (even after applying Smooth) along its length is not optimal.

How can I evenly space the Y axis loop vertices given that I know the end points for each sections, WHILE ALSO maintaining their overall section profiles (that's the really important part). ?

Using the Loop tool> Space tool on the section loops fundamentally changes the shape of the loop. I need to freeze the loop's shape -- just need to slide/distribute the Y loop vertices evenly along the length of each of the sections without distorting/changing their shape. I know I can do this manually with SHIFT V for each of the vertices on each of the sections, but that's really, really tedious and not very precise and I'm hoping to avoid needing to do that.

Ideas?
Thanks.

EDIT: And an addition to the blend file I've added below:  If I use Space I'm also getting this "rotation" of the vertices.. like:
[image]

to this:

[image]

Comment: Can you attach the blend using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com ? Because LoopTools -> Space feature does the job for me - it doesn't change the shape.

Comment: added: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6611" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6611/)

what settings did you use to get it to work as expected?

Another problem I have is that if I apply space to these 3 test loops, the loops also "rotate" around y a bit too. Not sure how to fix that too.